# Xamarin Forms InitializeComponent randomly hangs for iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms, freeze

While developing Xamarin.Forms application for (iOS and Android) I encountered a situation that in iOS only certain ContentPages (their Xaml is not a small file - around 1000 Lines) very randomly freeze while procesing InitializeComponent. I have an impression that the assembly was not loaded properly or so. While testing app I observe debug info on Mac Console and cannot figure out the real reason - no meaningful message is there - UI just freezes in 25% of the same scenario. I apply [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] attribute for faster Xaml loading but no difference when compilation is off. Can the Xaml size or complexity cause this random freeze of UI? Has anyone encountered such problem so far?
Thanks
JK

## Configuration

Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1821,
VisualStudio 2019 16.11.15 on Windows10PRO,
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 15.2.0.17,
macOS Monterey 12.4
XCode13.4

Comment: When you say "freeze", does the app eventually start working? XAML does take time to load, especially for nested layouts or layouts with a lot of bindings. Xamarin has some tips for [improving performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance) on XAML layouts. It you may also make sure that you don't have a memory leak or something by holding onto an old layout.

Comment: Unfortunately a random freeze is not easy to debug. I recommend commenting out different parts of the xaml (and any references in xaml.cs). Determine if it is certain xaml that causes it. Likely suspects are a ListView or CollectionView with a complicated ItemTemplate - test with a simple ItemTemplate to see if it stops freezing. Then gradually add the lines back in.

Comment: But it happens randomly adn if I was to point to the suspect it would be Xaml size - is it possible that xaml should not be too large? 95kB is too much?

Comment: OK problem solved - while executing InitializeComponent certain events as OnSizeAllocated are fired so when there is some code manipulating the layout this may randomly fail. This code should be active after the view has been created. Now everything seems to work. Thank you for advices.